# Crash when installing from usb drive

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

2010 iMac
I'm trying to install Freya from a usb drive. I get to the menu with the initial 4 options and choose "install elementary OS". The screen clears and I see about 4 lines of terminal text. Then there's a small pause and it says "controller not found". Then the screen goes dark and the computer is unresponsive.
I did check the hash of the iso before I burned it (using unetbootin) and it was fine.

Edit: after some googling, it seems like the issue may be that I need to enable "nomodeset" when installing. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it.

Press "e" on the boot screen to edit the loading command. Go to where it says "quiet splash" and type " nomodeset" after that. Press F10 to boot.